# SQL - Identifying Matching Values/Records From Two Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

1. tblCurrent
2. tblHistory

In each table, there i have an ID field that represents a product ID

1. tblCurrent - prodID
2. tblHistory - histID

These ID's (product IDs)  are the same.

I'm trying to write an SQL statement that identifies ID's that are present in tblCurrent but NOT in tblHistory

...and another statement that identifies ID's that are present in both tables

I've tried:

```
SELECT Distinct prodID
 FROM tblCurrent
INTERSECT
SELECT histID
 FROM tblHistory
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For IDs present in `tblCurrent` and not in `tblHistory`:

```
SELECT c.prodId FROM tblCurrent c
LEFT JOIN tblHistory h ON c.prodId = h.histId
WHERE c.prodId IS NULL
```

For IDs present in both:

```
SELECT c.prodId FROM tblCurrent c
JOIN tblHistory h ON c.prodId = h.histId
```

Note that if they are really IDs (unique) then you don't need the `DISTINCT` as there won't be multiple rows for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT Distinct prodID
 FROM tblCurrent WHERE prodID
NOT IN(
SELECT histID
 FROM tblHistory )

SELECT Distinct prodID
 FROM tblCurrent WHERE 
NOT EXISTS(
SELECT * 
 FROM tblHistory )


SELECT Distinct prodID
 FROM tblCurrent WHERE 
NOT EXISTS(
SELECT * 
 FROM tblHistory WHERE histID = tblCurrent.prodID )
```

[**NOT EXISTS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)